# What's wrong with visual code, add watching assembly code

Tags: visual-studio, assembly

I'm newbie to Assembly and visual studio.
I'm trying to 'add watch' my asm variables, but it seem's not working.
In watch windows, it's supposed to display as
name: rax  , value : 111
But it keeps displaying like the picture.
Why the 'add Watch' doesn't functioning well in my vs?
ps: visual studio 2019  / x64 / build customization file: masm

[image]

Comment: You breaked on the `mov` instruction, the line has not yet been executed.

Comment: @Lennart You are genius. Thank you.  solved this problem by breaking on 'ret' line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a breakpoint is hit, the line it is on is not yet executed. You can either set the breakpoint ond `ret` oder press F10 to step over the current statement.